# Hiding/Showing Dash Component based on a condition (Python Dash)

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-dash

I want to show or hide a button based on some value I get using Dash, for example:

```
If value > 10
   show button
else 
   hide button
```

Any help with an easy example is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50213761/changing-visibility-of-a-dash-component-by-updating-other-component. This link was some how similar but still not clear to me.