# Changing visibility of a Dash Component by updating other Component - 'hidden' as default

Tags: python, plotly, show-hide, plotly-dash

I refer to this question: [Changing visibility of a Dash Component by updating other Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50213761/changing-visibility-of-a-dash-component-by-updating-other-component).

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50417291/11857780)  shows how to hide a component, after choosing the respective value in a drop-down menu. I want to unhide components which are hidden as default. I tried the code from the accepted answer:

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash('example')

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='dropdown-to-show_or_hide-element',
        options=[
            {'label': 'Show element', 'value': 'on'},
            {'label': 'Hide element', 'value': 'off'}
        ],
        value='on'
    ),

    # Create Div to place a conditionally visible element inside
    html.Div([
        # Create element to hide/show, in this case an 'Input Component'
        dcc.Input(
            id='element-to-hide',
            placeholder='something',
            value='Can you see me?',
            )
        ], style={'display': 'none'} # <-- This is the line that will be changed by the dropdown callback
        )
    ])

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='element-to-hide', component_property='style'),
    [Input(component_id='dropdown-to-show_or_hide-element', component_property='value')])
def show_hide_element(visibility_state):
    if visibility_state == 'on':
        print('on')
        return {'display': 'block'}
    if visibility_state == 'off':
        print('off')
        return {'display': 'none'}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The only thing I've changed is this line of code

```
], style={'display': 'block'} # <-- This is the line that will be changed by the dropdown
```

to

```
], style={'display': 'none'} # <-- This is the line that will be changed by the dropdown
```

But when I run the app the input component is not shown at all. Even if I switch the drop-down to 'on'.

Is it possible to have hidden components by default and to unhide them later? And if not, why can I override the value from the display-style parameter from 'block' to 'none' but not from 'none' to 'block'?

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely do what you want to. I think the problem is coming from your conflicting default states. The component is hidden on load, but the dropdown's initial value is `"on"`, which seems to be messing things up. I'm not sure why it isn't updating correctly, but changing the initial style to `{'display': 'block'}` worked. Changing the initial dropdown value to `"off"` did not work.

It should be possible to have things hidden by default, though I'm not sure why it isn't working in this case.