# How to fire a modal after a double click on data points in a graph in Plotly Dash application

Tags: python, callback, plotly, plotly-dash

I have included a modal component into my dash application poping up after clicking on a data point inside a graph. I would like however to show the modal only after a second click on the data point confirming that the user really wants the modal to appear and not only clicked by accident. For the moment, I use the ‘Clickdata’ property of the graph component to trigger the callback responsible for the modal. Is there some other property that records how many time a data point was clicked for example, that way I could set the condition to number_of_clicks = 2 (or something alike … ) .

Thank you all for any helpful insight.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there are any properties of a graph component that allow you to store clicks, but you can extract click information through `clickData` and store that information in `dcc.Store`.

Since you didn't provide any specific code in your question, these are some of the assumptions built into my working example:

- that we are using a DataFrame for the data (which allows us to more conveniently store the number of clicks using a dictionary with the data point's `index` in the dataframe as the key and the number of clicks as the value). for example, `dcc.Store` might contain `{'0': 1}` meaning that the data point at index 0 has been clicked 1 time.
- that you want the modal component to appear *permanently* once any point is clicked twice.
- that the modal component you are using has the `style` property, which we will set to {'display': 'none'} so it is not visible when the app first renders, but will become visible once any point is clicked twice (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50213761/changing-visibility-of-a-dash-component-by-updating-other-component)). i picked `dcc.TextArea` but it could be any modal component that you like (this also works for double clicking on an individual point, thanks to @Hamzah's [helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75287491/how-to-fire-a-modal-after-a-double-click-on-data-points-in-a-graph-in-plotly-das))

---

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import dash
from dash import Input, Output, dcc, html, ctx
from typing import List

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': list(range(5,10)),
    'y': list(range(5,10))
})

fig = px.scatter(df, x='x', y='y')
fig.update_traces(marker_size=20)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(figure=fig, id='graph-interaction'),
        dcc.Store(id='store-clicks')
    ]),
    html.Div([
        # Create element to hide/show, in this case an 'Input Component'
        dcc.Textarea(
            id='modal',
            value='This shows up when you click a point twice',
            style={'width': 100, 'height': 100},
        ),
    ], style= {'display': 'none', 'padding-left': '80px'} # <-- This is the line that will be changed by the dropdown callback
    )
])

@app.callback(
    Output('modal','style'),
    Output('store-clicks','data'),
    Output('graph-interaction', 'clickData'),
    [Input('graph-interaction', 'clickData'),
    Input('store-clicks','data'),
    ])
def show_selection(click_data, stored_clicks):
    # print(f"incoming click data: {click_data}")
    if stored_clicks is None:
        stored_clicks = {}
    else:
        point_index = str(click_data['points'][0]['pointIndex'])
        if point_index in stored_clicks:
            stored_clicks[point_index] += 1
        else:
            stored_clicks[point_index] = 1
    
    ## this means that the model componant will appear permanently 
    ## after any point is clicked twice 
    if 2 in stored_clicks.values():
        return {'display': 'block'}, stored_clicks, None
    else:
        return {'display': 'none'}, stored_clicks, None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

In the example below, I click on the points `(6,6)` and `(7,7)` one time each, and once I click on `(8,8)` twice, the textbox appears.

[image]